# How to analyse the warning - Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints - iOS autolayout

Tags: ios7, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Somebody please explain how we can analyse the following warning associated with autolayout constraints in iOS7.

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this:

1. look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
2. find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

(

```
"< NSLayoutConstraint:0xd9e9920 V:[UIView:0x1e775630(24)]>",
"< NSLayoutConstraint:0x1e7af840 V:|-(568)-[UIView:0x1e775630]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1e72f480 )>",
"< NSLayoutConstraint:0x150a8cc0 V:[UIView:0x1e775630]-(0)-[UIView:0x1508ebd0]>",
"< NSLayoutConstraint:0x1509f680 V:[UIView:0x1508ebd0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1e72f480 )>",
"< NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x2491e4c0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x1e72f480(568)]>"
)
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd9e9920 V:[UIView:0x1e775630(24)]>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It can be anyone of the following problems.

- If you use Autolayout in programmatically then you need to turned
     off    the AutoresizingMask. It can be a problem.

> [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

OR

- In other way, you have added one extra constraints for your view.
  So, it can't satisfy the all constraints for your view. So, that's a
  issue.

> NSLayoutConstraint:0xd9e9920 V:[UIView:0x1e775630(24)]

You need to remove the vertical constraint which has value 24 for your view.